# Good reference on Devanagari typography and alphabet learning

Tags: writing-system, hindi, devanagari, sanskrit

I noticed nice fonts such as [this](https://www.behance.net/gallery/28902833/Free-Typeface-Devanagari-font-Ananda-ukaliorali) or [this](https://fontstand.com/fonts/brahmos-devanagari) for devanagari:

[image]
(Copyright [Ananda K. Maharjan](https://www.behance.net/gallery/28902833/Free-Typeface-Devanagari-font-Ananda-ukaliorali); licence: Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial)

I am used to seeing more curvy fonts such as this:

[image]

I would like to know if there are good resources for a beginning learner to learn how to *write* the alphabet like basically a child would, something very simple. And I would also like to know if there are any good or standard references on the orthography or details of what is and isn't allowed in terms of letter shape and structure.

I am looking for something free/open if possible.

Comment: Please add the source and copyright of the second image. Otherwise, the image is a copyright infringement and needs to be deleted. In addition, questions about typography are off-topic on this site, but questions about learning resources are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are books that teach you how to write Devanagari, for example,

- Rupert Snell: [*Read and Write Hindi Script*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/read-and-write-hindi-script/oclc/659756433). Teach Yourself. McGraw-Hill, 2010.
- Elvira Friedrich: *Einführung in die indischen Schriften. Teil 1: Devanāgari*. Third edition. Hamburg: Helmut Buske, 2012.

You can also find many YouTube videos that teach you how to write Devanagari, such as those I listed in the question [Are there any accurate online resources for learning to write Devanagari?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2984/800).

Comment: The YouTube videos in the question I referenced are free. Also, since the rules of a writing system change only *very* slowly, I don't see why the resources would need to be more recent than 2011 or 2012.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's already been mentioned, DuoLingo has a Hindi track, which includes a section on learning the letters. It has an interactive page for each letter that lets you trace the strokes, along with exercises for learning the sounds of each letter.
[image: Tracing the Devanagari letter a]

Sometimes there are mistakes in the audio, but generally it will give you a good boost in learning the alphabet.